# UnknownHostException on Spring Roo osgi start command

Tags: spring-roo

I'm doing first steps with Spring Roo addon dev-t.
Generating and building "simple addon" completed successfully. But at last step I've got strange error message.

**java.net.UnknownHostException: target
Bundle ID file://target/org.home.roo.addon.hello-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar is invalid.**

Target directory and jar do exist.
I can't understand even nature of this error. Could you please give me an idea what I did wrong or missed?

```
C:\sts_workspaceRooAddOn\spring-roo-addon-hello> roo addon create simple --topLevelPackage org.home.roo.addon.hello
    ____  ____  ____
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \
  / /_/ / / / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.2.2.RELEASE [rev 7d75659]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
Created ROOT\pom.xml
Created ROOT\readme.txt
Created ROOT\legal
Created ROOT\legal\LICENSE.TXT
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\org\home\roo\addon\hello
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\org\home\roo\addon\hello\HelloCommands.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\org\home\roo\addon\hello\HelloOperations.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\org\home\roo\addon\hello\HelloOperationsImpl.java
Created SRC_MAIN_JAVA\org\home\roo\addon\hello\HelloPropertyName.java
Created ROOT\src\main\assembly
Created ROOT\src\main\assembly\assembly.xml
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES\org\home\roo\addon\hello
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES\org\home\roo\addon\hello\info.tagx
Created SRC_MAIN_RESOURCES\org\home\roo\addon\hello\show.tagx

C:\sts_workspaceRooAddOn\spring-roo-addon-hello>mvn clean install
...
...
[INFO] Installing org/home/roo/addon/hello/org.home.roo.addon.hello/0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/org.home.roo.addon.hello-0.1
.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Writing OBR metadata
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.268s

C:\sts_workspaceRooAddOn\spring-roo-addon-hello>roo osgi start --url file://target/org.home.roo.addon.hello-0.1.0.BUILD
-SNAPSHOT.jar
    ____  ____  ____
   / __ \/ __ \/ __ \
  / /_/ / / / / / / /
 / _, _/ /_/ / /_/ /
/_/ |_|\____/\____/    1.2.2.RELEASE [rev 7d75659]


Welcome to Spring Roo. For assistance press TAB or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
0 upgrades available (plus 35 upgrades not visible due to your version stability setting of RELEASE)
java.net.UnknownHostException: target
Bundle ID file://target/org.home.roo.addon.hello-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar is invalid.
```

Comment: I've try different url without any success
osgi start --url file://c:/sts_workspaceRooAddOn/spring-roo-addon-hello/target/org.canon.roo.addon.hello-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
osgi start --url file://target/org.canon.roo.addon.hello-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
C:\sts_workspaceRooAddOn\spring-roo-addon-hello\target>roo
roo> osgi start --url file://org.canon.roo.addon.hello-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar

The result is always the same

java.net.UnknownHostException: target
Is there nobody who can help me with that issue?
Any suggestion or hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You are instructing it to open a file URL to <current_working_directory>/target/org.home.roo.addon.hello-0.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar.  You assume that <current_working_directory> is the root of your project...maybe its not?  Maybe instead of giving it a relative path, give it an absolute page?